# mobileapp css background image problems on monaca

Tags: monaca

I am new to building apps with monaca. I have built a lot of websites with css and html  , so am very familiar with the language .
Anyway , when i give a background image to the navigation bar with css like this

```css
 background: url(img/header.png);
```

it works in the preview emulator, but when i run/sync it with my phone the image doesnt show on it.  i am running it on my samsung galaxy s5
I am beginning to wonder if theres a right way of doing it on monaca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this property to the style of your toolbar: `background-size: contain`.
It works for me in Monaca preview and debugger. For some reason the image size is different.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size